# How hook observable starting on delayed subscription in rxjava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

**Usability:** When user press button, search starts after 3000 msec. When search starts, progress bar should be shown.

I have delayed subscription:

```
Observable<SearchResult> delayedSearch = search
.delaySubscription(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
//not working
.doOnSubscribe(() -> log(should appear progress bar))

delayedSearch.subscribe(result -> log(should disappear progress bar));
```

**Problem:** I can't hook start observable's execution.
How best way to solve problem? Or maybe another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.
I create showProgress observable:

```
Observable showProgress = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            log("showProgress")
            subscriber.onNext(null);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

and add it before searching:

```
Observable<SearchResult> searchWithProgress = showProgress.flatMap((Func1) o -> search);
```

So I can use it like this:

```
Observable<SearchResult> delayedSearch = searchWithProgress.delaySubscription(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

delayedSearch.subscribe(result -> log(hideProgress);
```